# Return value of an malloc() for a structure type

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct student
{
  int roll_no;
  int mark;
  struct student *p;
};

int main()
{
  struct student *stu;
  stu = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
}
```

What is the actual return value of `malloc()` for a structure type? How is it being assigned to the structure variable?

Now for the statement,

```
struct student *stu;
```

Memory allocation like `stu` with 4 bytes lets just say starting from `1000`.

And for the statement

```
stu = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
```

First allocates block of memory, let's just say `2000` - `2012`. Then the assignment part a pointer to `2000` stored at `1000`.

This is how the assignment part works for `malloc()` and structure variable.

And now pointer i.e `stu` holding the starting address `2000`. So now `stu->roll_no` will access the 1st 4 bytes and `stu->mark` will access the next 4 bytes and so on. The question is how does the compiler understand it, it's not like `stu->roll_no` is equivalent to `*(stu+0)` and `stu->mark` is equivalent to `*(stu+1)`. Explanation to this will be much appreciated.

Comment: `Struct student *stu;` doesn't allocate anything but the pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the precise answer. Now lets say Block of Memory(BOM) be from 2000 to 2012.     Pointer i.e the stu holding the starting adr 2000. So now stu->roll_no will acess the 1st 4 bytes and stu->mark will access the next 4 bytes and so on. The question is how does the compiler will understand it, Its not like stu->roll_no is equivalent to *(stu+0) and stu->mark is equivalent to *(stu+1). Explanation to this will be much appreciated.

Comment: You didn't got the syntax right, but the compiler will indeed simply add some offset to the pointer and dereference it. `stu->mark` could be something like `*((int *)stu + 1)`.

Comment: Thank you for ur valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc()` returns a pointer to a block of memory (`void *`) large enough to hold `size` (first argument) bytes regardless of what the argument is or what the result is being casted to.

For example, `stu->roll_no` would access the first four bytes (assuming `int` is 32-bit) of the allocated memory (assuming that the structure is not padded).

In C, `void *` pointers are implicitly converted into the pointer type of what they are assigned to.

Your understanding is correct except for this statement:

> And for clarity sake, unlike a normal structure variable which will allocate 12 bytes for the struct student whereas a structure pointer variable allocates just 4 bytes.

The pointer to the structure is allocated on the stack in this case and the structure itself is allocated on the heap. If you had used a structure directly,  it would allocate 12 bytes on the stack and no bytes on the heap.

You're correct on this:

> it's not like `stu->roll_no` is equivalent to `*(stu+0)` and `stu->mark` is equivalent to `*(stu+1)`

`stu->roll_no` is equivalent to `*((int *)stu+0)` and `stu->mark` is equivalent to `*((int *)stu+1)`. Note the casts to `int *`.

Answer (score -1):

malloc return void * pointer to a place in the memory in size you sent it that you can cast to any - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm type you want see malloc definition :
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm